# Creating typescript type from union of two ReadOnly arrays

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following typescript code, where I define two read only arrays and then create a type based on the union of those two arrays. However, vscode does not give me any intellisense when I try to define a variable of type `Note`. Why is that? Is there a better to solution to what I am trying to achieve here?

```
const allNotes = ["A",
    "A#",
    "B",
    "C",
    "C#",
    "D",
    "D#",
    "E",
    "F",
    "F#",
    "G",
    "G#",] as const

const allNotesWithFlats = [
    "A",
    "Bb",
    "B",
    "C",
    "Db",
    "D",
    "Eb",
    "E",
    "F",
    "Gb",
    "G",
    "Ab"
]
type Note = typeof allNotes[number] | typeof allNotesWithFlats[number];

const n : Note = '' // No intellisense
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `as const` by the second array:

```
const allNotes = ["A",
    "A#",
    "B",
    "C",
    "C#",
    "D",
    "D#",
    "E",
    "F",
    "F#",
    "G",
    "G#",] as const

const allNotesWithFlats = [
    "A",
    "Bb",
    "B",
    "C",
    "Db",
    "D",
    "Eb",
    "E",
    "F",
    "Gb",
    "G",
    "Ab"
] as const
type Note = typeof allNotes[number] | typeof allNotesWithFlats[number];

const n : Note = '' // No intellisense
```

That worked fine for me.